# Z3: solving ite example using C API

Tags: c, z3, solver, smt

I am a newcomer in Z3 solver, and using Windows 10, VS2013 command prompt.

I am trying to use C and I have tried to solve the below simple problem using Z3 solver.

problem set: what is the possible value of a that satisfies (b = 1) condition for below if-then-else statement,

(Here, we are looking for the solution of (a = 1))

```
if (a = 1)
  b = 1
else
  b = 0
```

So I made below C code, based on the C code example of Z3,

(but the code is not working because it does not make sense at all using Z3, and I sincerely apologize for that)

```
void ite_example()
{
    Z3_context ctx = mk_context();
    Z3_solver  s = mk_solver(ctx);
    Z3_model m = 0;
    Z3_ast a, b, one, zero, ite, ite_true;
    Z3_ast a_eq_one, b_eq_one, b_eq_zero;
    Z3_ast c1;

    printf("\nite_example\n");

    one = mk_int(ctx, 1);
    zero = mk_int(ctx, 0);
    a = mk_int_var(ctx, "a");
    b = mk_int_var(ctx, "b");

    a_eq_one = Z3_mk_eq(ctx, b, one);
    b_eq_one = Z3_mk_eq(ctx, a, one);
    b_eq_zero = Z3_mk_eq(ctx, a, zero);

    ite = Z3_mk_ite(ctx, a_eq_one, b_eq_one, b_eq_zero); // if(a = 1) then(b = 1) else(b = 0)
    Z3_solver_assert(ctx, s, ite);

    // we want to find the integer variable (a) that makes (b = 1)
    c1 = Z3_mk_eq(ctx, b, one);
    Z3_solver_assert(ctx, s, c1);

    m = Z3_solver_get_model(ctx, s);
    printf("%s\n", Z3_model_to_string(ctx, m));

    /* delete logical context */
    Z3_del_context(ctx);
}

int main() {
    #ifdef LOG_Z3_CALLS
        Z3_open_log("z3.log");
    #endif
        ite_example();
        return 0;
}
```

But it seems that the code is not working (generating error code as below)

```
D:\z3-master\z3-master\build>make examples
cl /nologo /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /O2 /Oy- /D _EXTERNAL_RELEASE /D WIN32 /D NDEBUG /D _CONSOLE /D _WINDOWS /D ASYNC_COMMANDS /Gm- /EHsc /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Gd /analyze- /arch:SSE2  /openmp /MD /D _WINDOWS  /Fotest_capi2.obj /nologo /MD -I..\src\api ..\examples\c\test_capi2.c
test_capi2.c
cl /Fec_example.exe /nologo /MD test_capi2.obj  libz3.lib /link /DEBUG /MACHINE:X86 /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /INCREMENTAL:NO /STACK:8388608 /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT
Z3 examples were successfully built.

D:\z3-master\z3-master\build>c_example.exe

ite_example
Error code: 10
BUG: incorrect use of Z3.
```

I am so sorry for asking you so much elementary problem.

Any idea on how to solve this problem will be very appreciated.

(the revised ite_example code will be very much appreciated!)

Thank you very much.

Sincerely,
Lee.

Comment: You first need to ask `z3` to check the *satisfiability* of the problem (something like `Z3_solver_check(ctx, s)` I guess), double-check that the search result is `Z3_L_TRUE`, and only then you can retrieve a model by calling `Z3_solver_get_model(ctx, s)`.